# Translation: Self-Conscious

Tags: translation

In English we use 'self-conscious' to mean 'conscious (or worried) about oneself' like:

The cameras made her feel self-conscious about her weight.

Or

Don't mention his acne, he's really self-conscious about it.

Dictionaries have words like 害羞，难为情的，尴尬 but that doesn't seem to really fit...

Any ideas?

Comment: I think 尴尬 fits in the second example, for instance, 不要提他的痤疮因为这会让他尴尬/他觉得这很尴尬...

Comment: I actually cannot think of a Chinese word that describe this embarrassing feeling caused by self-awareness! I don't think 害羞 nor 自觉 are precise enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I am to translate:

The cameras made her self-conscious about her weight:

拍照让他在意起自己的体重

Don't mention his acne, he's really self-conscious about it.

别提起他的暗疮，他很介意。

PS: I suppose you were right, we might not really have a definite word/phrase for its translation, but i'd say it is very close to 介意/在意

Comment: How about: He's self-conscious about his Chinese?

Comment: Well that would then be 他很清楚自己的华文程度

Comment: 好委婉哦 - nice a subtle, hey?

Answer (score 2):

In Japanese, they use the kanji phrase "自意識過剰" to express "self-conscious". I think it is a good reference. In my opinion, "太過神經質" is perhaps a good translation in Chinese.

For example,

"他那樣做不是因為你的關係，請不要太過神經質了。"

That he did that thing is not because of you. Please don't be too self-conscious.